# Do I need to recreate my index after changing the type of one of the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Entries :

It has : **EntryID, EntryTime, Type, Values**

**EntryID, EntryTime** are primary keys.

I have a composite index  `(EntryID,EntryTime)`

The problem is, when i created the table some months ago, **EntryTime** type was **VARCHAR**. Now i have changed it to **DateTime** recently.

Do i need to recreate the **EntryTime index** ?

NB: If was in **VARCHAR** before because, i was accepting some corrupted time values as well which will normally not be possible had it been in **DATETIME** format.But now i cleaned it up and changed it to DATETIME. The table has a million records now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, If you have ran `alter` query to change the datatype, It automatically creates indexes again, so you don't need to do it again.

> Changing the data type of a column causes a table restructure, which will have the side-effect of rebuilding all indexes for the table (not only those referencing the column you altered, but all indexes in that table).

You can also check you indexes by query `show indexes from tablename;`

source: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60526/what-effect-does-changing-the-data-type-of-an-existing-indexed-field-have-on-the).